# FragmentTransaction: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created a brand new "Empty Activity" Android Studio project. The project will no longer compile after following the simple official Android [Create a fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create) docs:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        supportFragmentManager.commit {
            setReorderingAllowed(true)
            add<ExampleFragment>(R.id.fragment_container_view)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is my project on GitHub showing only 1 commit where I followed the aforementioned Android docs:
https://github.com/rajohns08/createfragment/commit/866b2d2e74e99964e61d3b1bb89521b0f6c184b9

Here is the commit diff image for posterity:

[image]

I'm on Android Studio Bumblebee Patch 1. My `compileSdk` and `targetSdk` are 31, and my `minSdk` is 28 as can be seen in the GitHub source.

Comment: Did you import the `add` Kotlin extension function that you're trying to use?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, nope that was the issue thanks!